# Generate inline formset in django using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, model

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RdcE.jpg)
I have used inlineformset_factory for generating multiple instances of the same model. I want to make it dynamic. So I have a + button, when the user presses this button same form will be generated. I also want to keep a delete button for deleting. I have written a jquery function for this work. But when I click + button, nothing happens. No form generates.

forms.py:

```
WorkExperienceFormset = inlineformset_factory(Employee, WorkExperience, extra=1,
                                                fields = [
                                                    'previous_company_name',
                                                    'job_designation',
                                                    'from_date',
                                                    'to_date',
                                                    'job_description',
                                                ],
                                                widgets = {
                                                        'previous_company_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
                                                        'job_designation': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
                                                        'from_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm has-feedback-left single_cal', 'id': 'single_cal3'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
                                                        'to_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm has-feedback-left single_cal', 'id': 'single_cal4'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
                                                        'job_description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
                                                }
                                            )
```

WorkExperience model is related with Employee model as ForeignKey.
employee_work_experience_form.html.html:

```
<!-- Manage collection of forms -->
{{ work_formset.management_form }}

<!-- Handle formset errors -->
{% for work_form in work_formset %}
  {{ work_form.non_field_errors }}
  {{ work_form.errors }}
{% endfor %}

{% for work_form in work_formset %}
<div class="work-form">
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">Previous Company Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <!-- <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
      {{ work_form.previous_company_name }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">Job Designation</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <!-- <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
      {{ work_form.job_designation }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">Job Details</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <!-- <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
      {{ work_form.job_description }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">From Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      <!-- <input id="birthday" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text"> -->
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        {{ work_form.from_date }}
        <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left m-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 label-align">To Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      <!-- <input id="birthday" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text"> -->
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        {{ work_form.to_date }}
        <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left m-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

I am including this html to main employee_form.html as include template tag.

```
<h4>Work Experience</h4>
                <button type="button" value="add" id="add_work_experience"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                {% include 'employee/employee_work_experience_form.html' %}
```

jquery:

```
 // Add work experience
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#add_work_experience').click(function() {
        cloneMore('work-form', 'work_form');
      });
    });


    function cloneMore(selector, type) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
}
```

when I click + button nothing happens. I don't know the problem.

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide some insight about what works and what doesn't in your code so others can help ? You also can look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com for a better code review platform, where these types of questions are better recieved.

Comment: @Leogout I have edited